# NGINX caching for HTTPS

Tags: caching, nginx, https

I am exploring Nginx cache, everything works as long as I access the resource through HTTP . But as soon as I use HTTPS , Nginx dont put data in cache. I always see MISS in response headers. Does I need to do anything extra for HTTPS or ignore few headers which gets added by default for HTTPS ?

I see HIT when I access the same resource through HTTP which was not working in HTTPS. And once it gets cached HTTPS also return from the cahce as I can see HIT in response header. Somehow HTTPS is not able to put in the cache.
tried below setting also
proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie; proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie; proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  It was becauuse of proxy_buffer  in HTTPS. Removed it. working fine now.

Comment: Hi, could you please share the example of nginx config file?